# EWS sometime fail to send / reply / move emails

Tags: exchangewebservices, exchange-server-2007

I have two EWS(Exchange Web Service Managed API) instances to connect to the same Exchange Sever 2007 mail account:

1. The instance in service which is fired every 6 seconds to move or send or forward email(s).
2. The instance in web application which the user can get the email information or sending an email.

Normally, my both applications work correctly. However, there are sometimes that the EWS functions seem to be malfunction such as

- The moving task of EWS instance LOST email, I have check every place (Source Inbox, Destination box and delete box) the email seem to be invisibly gone.
- The moving email and forwarding task of EWS instance NO ACT, I have try manually moving the related email to another box (such as Draft box), waiting for 6 seconds, moving to the old Inbox again. The email then was pulled into the proper box and the forwarding occurred (working properly).

I have try to research about EWS multithread, but my application is not mutually relevant and neither get the thread detail of another. What causes do you think about my problem?